# How can I achieve something like Svelte's deferred transitions in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svelte, svelte-3

I'm basically looking for something like Svelte's `in:receive` and `out:receive`.

You can see what it does in the Svelte Tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/deferred-transitions.
It perfectly moves a todo from one list to another.

Is there something similar in Vue.js?

I've looked through this page: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Sarah Drasner did a whole article on these native type transitions where an element goes from one spot to another smoothly. [Here you go](https://css-tricks.com/native-like-animations-for-page-transitions-on-the-web/) it uses `<transition-group>` which applies the flip like Svelte's, the  docs for it are [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions)

Comment: That's a good article. The problem I have is that I do not know where my todo will go. Therefore I can not work with transforms as she did. I'm actually quite impressed by how easy Svelte achieves that animation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Vue don`t have that built-in support for the so-called defer transition technique. But you can leverage <transition-group> to have the same effects that cross-fade does.

Here is the vue implementation. I used setTimeout and FLIP technique to implement the crossfade effects.

The basic logic here is that we record the positions for both the send part and the receiving part, and use setTimeout to defer the transition(if we don`t do this, we can`t use [FLIP technique](https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/)).

visit [code pen link](https://codepen.io/li-jincheng/pen/NWdNOYG) to see the final effects

```
<!-- Use preprocessors via the lang attribute! e.g. <template lang="pug"> -->
<template>
  <div id="flip-list-demo" class="demo">
  <button @click="shuffle">shuffle</button>
  <input type="text" @keyup.enter="add" />
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
    <transition-group
      @before-enter="beforeEnter"
      @enter="enter"
      @leave="leave"
      name="list"
      tag="div"
    >
      <li
        class="list-item"
        v-for="(item, index) in validList"
        v-bind:key="item.value"
        :ref="item.value"
        @click="goInvalid"
        :data-item="item.value"
      >
        {{ item.value }}
      </li>
    </transition-group>
    <transition-group
      name="list"
      @before-enter="beforeEnter"
      @enter="enter"
      @leave="leave"
      tag="div"
    >
      <li
        :ref="item.value"
        class="list-item"
        v-for="(item, index) in invalidList"
        :key="item.value"
        @click="goValid"
        :data-item="item.value"
      >
        {{ item.value }}
      </li>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  const items = (function () {
  const val = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    val.push({
      value: i,
      valid: true
    });
  }
  return val;
})();
const sendRectMap = new Map();
const receiveRectMap = new Map();

export default {
  data: {
    items
  },
  computed: {
    invalidList: function () {
      return this.items.filter((i) => !i.valid);
  },
  validList: function () {
    return this.items.filter((i) => i.valid);
  }
},
methods: {
  beforeEnter(el) {
     el.style.opacity = 0;

    setTimeout(() => {
      const item = el.dataset.item;
      const to = receiveRectMap.get(item);
      const from = sendRectMap.get(item);

      const dx = from.left - to.left;
      const dy = from.top - to.top;
      const dw = from.width / to.width;
      const dh = from.height / to.height;
      const d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

      el.style.transition = "all 0ms";
      el.style.transform = `translate(${dx}px, ${dy}px)`;
    }, 0);
  },
  enter(el, done) {
    console.log("enter");
    console.log(el);
    console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect());

    const to = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const item = el.dataset.item;

    // get receiving part position in 'enter' and put it into receiveRectMap(that is 
    how Sevlet does in cross-fade)
    receiveRectMap.set(item, to);

    setTimeout(() => {
      el.style.transition = "all 300ms";
      el.style.transform = "";
      el.style.opacity = 1;
      el.style.display = "block";
    }, 20);

    done();
  },

  leave(el, done) {
    console.log("before leave");
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect);

    // get sending part position in 'leave' function and put it into 
    receiveRectMap(that is how Sevlet does in cross-fade)
    sendRectMap.set(el.dataset.item, rect);

    el.style.display = "none";

  },

  goInvalid(e) {
    const el = e.target;
    const item = el.dataset.item;
    const index = this.items.findIndex((i) => i.value.toString() === item);
    this.$set(
      this.items,
      index,
      Object.assign({}, this.items[index], { valid: false })
    );
  },
  goValid(e) {
    const el = e.target;
    const item = el.dataset.item;
    const index = this.items.findIndex((i) => i.value.toString() === item);
    this.$set(
      this.items,
      index,
      Object.assign({}, this.items[index], { valid: true })
    );
  },
  shuffle: function () {
    this.items = _.shuffle(this.items);
  },
  add(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.items.push({ value, valid: true });
    this.items = Object.assign([], this.items);
  }
 }
};
</script>

<!-- Use preprocessors via the lang attribute! e.g. <style lang="scss"> -->
<style>


.list-item {
  transition: all 500ms;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

.list-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

[code pen link](https://codepen.io/li-jincheng/pen/NWdNOYG)